# flotchart xaxis show time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to show the time on xaxis using flot charts

here's my array of data (time, value)

```
var time = [["13:33","0.04668"],["13:23","0.04856"],["13:12","0.05997"],["13:01","0.04679"]];
```

and here's the flot chart settings

```
 $("#flot-dashboard-chart").length && $.plot($("#flot-dashboard-chart"), [
            time
        ],
        {
            series: {
                lines: {
                    show: false,
                    fill: true
                },
                splines: {
                    show: true,
                    tension: 0.4,
                    lineWidth: 1,
                    fill: 0.4
                },
                points: {
                    radius: 0,
                    show: true
                },
                shadowSize: 2
            },
            grid: {
                hoverable: true,
                clickable: true,
                tickColor: "#d5d5d5",
                borderWidth: 1,
                color: '#d5d5d5'
            },
            colors: ["#1ab394", "#464f88"],
            xaxis:{
                mode: "time",
                timeformat: "%H:%M"
            },
            yaxis: {
                ticks: 4
            },
            tooltip: false
        }
    );
```

it keeps coming up with the following error:

Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'quadraticCurveTo' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': 4 arguments required, but only 0 present.

if I replace the : in time with a . (dot) I don't get the error anymore however the xaxis does not show at all

```
var time = [["13.33","0.04668"],["13.23","0.04856"],["13.12","0.05997"],["13.01","0.04679"]];
```

Comment: Perhaps a fiddle would be nice.

Comment: Flot requires time to be in ms since epoch. You can't do 13:30. It needs to know the date. See https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data

Comment: @dman2306 thanks that was it! Unfortunately I cannot mark your comment as an answer as it's a comment. Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flot time series plugin works on milliseconds since the epoch (1/1/1970) which is very similar to UNIX time, except it's in milliseconds, not seconds. You'll need to provide the timestamp in that format. The [flot website](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#time-series-data) provides great examples of getting this in various languages. Also note, Flot is designed to work on UTC time so things will go a lot smoother if you convert your timestamps to UTC. In your example, it looks like you only want to show time, not date/time, so you can always format the axis string to display however you'd like. You can just pick a date and set all the times to be of a particular date and then just display the time component.

Note, as you play with Flot, you'll notice it's a bit quirky. Sometimes using multiple plugins together requires them to be loaded in a specific order and such. I've been using it for about a year and I've always been able to get it to do what I needed, sometimes it's just a bit trickier than it would seem it should be!